# CABasicAnimation On UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have a list page and detail page.In my list page there is a UITableView.
In my tableviewcell :

```
var buttonStyle: ButtonStyle = .Button {
    didSet {
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2.0)
        rotationAnimation.duration = 2
        rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        if oldValue != buttonStyle {
            switch buttonStyle {
            case .Button:
                self.loadingView.isHidden = true
                self.progressView.isHidden = true
                self.opertaionBtn.isHidden = false
                self.bringSubview(toFront: self.opertaionBtn)

            case .Loading:
                //self.loadingView.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
                self.loadingView.isHidden = false
                self.progressView.isHidden = true
                self.opertaionBtn.isHidden = true
                self.bringSubview(toFront: self.loadingView)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used to add the anime on the didSet. When the page back from the detail page, i set the buttonStyle to Loading and update the cell.But the animation doesn't move. So I write a function to put the animation.

```
func addAnimation() {
    var anime = self.loadingView.layer.animation(forKey: "rotationAnimation") as? CABasicAnimation
    if anime == nil {
        anime = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        anime.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2.0)
        anime.duration = 2
        anime.isCumulative = true
        anime.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        anime.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        self.loadingView.layer.add(anime, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

And when back to list page , i first set the buttonStyle and the `addAnimation()`. It works well. Anybody knows why? Thank you !

Comment: Fixed. Don't add animation on 'didSet' .Extract it to function and put it outside !